# Use remote server env variable in ksh via an SSH command

Tags: unix, ssh, ksh, env

I can't find any answer to this "easy looking" problem.

I would like to execute an ssh command using a ksh shell or script which use an env variable of the **SERVER**.

Example:
*ssh user@server "ls $DIR"*

Where $DIR is an env variable define on the **server** (in this case: a directory path) and not the $DIR define on my client env.

In worst case scenario I can use something like  *env | grep DIR | cut -d "=" -f 2*
to get the var but it looks weird.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh user@server "ls $DIR"
```

Double-quoted strings undergo variable interpolation. So "$DIR" is being replaced on the local system, then the shell invokes the ssh command with the resulting string.

To pass the literal command through to the remote system, use single quotes:

```
ssh user@server 'ls $DIR'
```

Answer (score 0):

The SSH command execution shell is a `non-interactive` shell, whereas your normal shell is either a `login` shell or an `interactive` shell.

In fact not all environment varialbles are available in non-interactive shell, you need to check `ksh` manual to figure out the configuration files that `ksh` reads when running in `non-interactive` mode, in case of `bash` those are roughly following

```
/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
```

Just find out the corresponding ones for `ksh` and move/copy your `DIR` environment variable definition to there on sever side.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have my variable in my .profile use by ksh on server side. But ssh still use the definition of the variable present client side (DIR is define on both environnement with different values). How can I make ssh understand I want to use the definition of the server ?

Comment: Ok I'm good now. By lauching my .profile at ssh session start and using Kenster answer syntax, I'm now using my remote variable.